# How to tweet from an Android app using REST API 1.1

Tags: android, twitter

Here I am posting some text from an Android app to a user's Twitter account, and I have ConsumerKey, Consumer secret key, AccessToken, and AccessToken secret key.

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json
```

By using simple a HTTP client request, I want to post data on a Twitter user account. How can I do that?

I tried something like

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json");

// HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://graph.facebook.com/" + profile_ID + "/feed");

System.out.println("httppost " + httppost);

try {
    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("access_token", access_token_value));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", compose.getText().toString()));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    System.out.println("response "+response.toString());

}
catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
```

But parameters are wrong in my code, [following this](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update), but I didn't get it so what is some suitable solution for this?

Comment: Yes ,it is asking for Login .But i want to post app data with out login

Comment: @SalmanAyub twitter4j is first choice for anyone ,who is working with twitter according to my requirement without login i want to tweet from my app and above info i have ,i didn't get by using above info how to post

Answer (score 1):

If you want to post what you have entered in text box, I may help you out here.

1. You must have included the twitter4j library in gradle file as follows:

   ```
    compile group: 'org.twitter4j', name: 'twitter4j-core', version: '4.0.1'
   ```
2. Include following code snippet in your code:

   public String sTweet;
   EditText et_TweetText;
   public static String consumerkey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
   public static String consumersecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
   public static String accesstoken="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
   public static String accesstokensecret="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   et_TweetText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_TweetText);

   ```
    bt_tweetIt = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bt_tweetIt);
    bt_tweetIt.setOnClickListener(this);
   ```

   }

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
   sTweet = et_TweetText.getText().toString();
   Log.i(TAGTweet, "onClick- sTweet: " + sTweet);

   if(CheckConnectivity()!=0){
   Log.i(TAGTweet, "Internet Connection ON: ");
   new UseTweeter().execute();
   }
   else {
   Log.i(TAGTweet, "Internet Connection OFF: ");
   ShowNoInternetConnectionAlert();
   }

}

```
public class UseTweeter extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{
     @Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
     TweetThisMessage();
    return null;
}
```

}

```
public void TweetThisMessage(){
ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
builder.setOAuthAccessToken(accesstoken);
builder.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(accesstokensecret);
builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(consumerkey);
builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(consumersecret);
OAuthAuthorization auth = new OAuthAuthorization(builder.build());
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance(auth);

try {
    Log.i(TAGTweet, "sTweet in TweetThisMessage(): " + sTweet);
    twitter.updateStatus(sTweet);
} catch (TwitterException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
}
```

}

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are asking for *How to tweet from an Android app using REST API 1.1*, I would recommend you to use the [Twitter 4j](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html) library, for integrating Twitter in your Android application.

This library encapsulates the authentication functionality (via an [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) library) and other important functionalities within itself. Here are some of its features:

Twitter4J is featuring:

- 100% pure Java - works on any Java Platform version 5 or later
- Android platform and [Google App Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_App_Engine)-ready
- Zero dependency: No additional [JAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_%28file_format%29) files required
- Built-in OAuth support
- Out-of-the-box gzip support
- 100% Twitter API 1.1 compatible

You need to call simple functions via this Library to use the specific functionality regarding Twitter. Here is a link that demonstrates the usage of this library:
http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html

You can download this library on the link http://twitter4j.org/.

Here is a sample implemented with the library https://github.com/itog/Twitter4j-android-Sample.